# Why does this Gutenberg-block use the previous value for getEntityRecord?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

When I enter a `hikeId` via the editor, `useSelect` always takes the previous entered value for `getEntityRecord`, not the current one.

I thought by setting the extra parameter `..., [ hikeId ]` on `useSelect`, React triggers it when `hikeId` changes, but apparently this is not the case.

How can I change the code so that `distance`, `duration` and `ascend` get fetched with the current value of `hikeId`?

Here is the complete code:

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';

const { useSelect } = wp.data;

const HikeSummaryData = ( props ) => {
    const {
        attributes: { hikeId, distance, duration, ascend },
        setAttributes,
    } = props;

    const postData = useSelect(select => {
        return hikeId
            ? select('core').getEntityRecord('postType', 'post', hikeId)
            : undefined;
    }, [ hikeId ]);

    const determineData = (value) => {
        setAttributes({
            hikeId: value,
            distance: postData && postData.meta ? postData.meta['alsnuff_hike_summary_distance_meta'] : -1,
            duration: postData && postData.meta ? postData.meta['alsnuff_hike_summary_duration_meta'] : -1,
            ascend: postData && postData.meta ? postData.meta['alsnuff_hike_summary_ascend_meta'] : -1
        });
    };

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Hike ID</legend>
                <TextControl
                    value={ hikeId }
                    onChange={ determineData }
                />
            </fieldset>

            <div class="card">
                <footer class="card-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Distanz: { distance != -1 ? (Math.floor(distance / 100) / 10) + 'km' : '-' }</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Dauer: { duration != -1 ? duration + 'h' : '-' }</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Aufstieg: { ascend != -1 ? ascend + 'm' : '-' }</a>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HikeSummaryData;
```

Comment: Could you please describe the purpose of the `HikeSummaryData` component? Does it act like a search results page based on the user entering a `hikeId`? Or is the purpose to copy hike data from the searched post into the current post? Or something else?

Comment: The author enters a `hikeId`, then info about the hike is collected from metadata and displayed.

Comment: Should users be using this meta data to update a post on the Edit Post page? I ask to understand the purpose of the component. Once I understand, I can propose a solution. It isn't clear why this functionality is present on an Edit Post page instead of a front-end page unless the intent is to use the meta data from Post B (the meta data searched by the user) to update Post A (the post originally displayed).

Comment: Ah, I got you. Yes, this is the code for an edit post page and yes, you are correct here, you can enter an id to get metadata from another post.

Comment: I ask if Post B's meta data should update (overwrite) Post A's data because that is what your code would (perhaps unintentionally) do if the user searched using `hikeId=B`, then clicked the Edit Post page's **Update** button. My guess is that you are using `attributes` and `setAttributes` for state management, rather than the purpose for which it was designed. I can post a more complete explanation in my answer if you can confirm whether or not your intention was to have Post B's meta data overwrite Post A's data. Thanks.

Comment: Post B's metadata should be used to fill the fields of this Gutenberg-block which would be in Post A. But, just to be clear, the intention is not to overwrite Post A's _metadata_ (which is not the case here, I can assure you).

Comment: So, it is ok that Post A's Gutenberg block `attributes.hikeId` value contain the `hikeId` of Post B? Or should Post A's `attributes.hikeId` remain stable as Post A's actual post ID?

Comment: Yes, Post A's Gutenberg block `attributes.hikeId` should be the `hikeId` (i.e. post ID that gets me the metadata for the hike) of Post B. Post A does not need to have an own "`hikeId`" (i.e. the metadata). And no, Post A's Gutenberg block `attributes.hikeId` shouldn't be Post A's actual post ID - I wouldn't need a Gutenberg block for that, no?

Comment: Also, it is possible to have multiple such Gutenberg blocks in Post A to show the metadata of several other Post Bs.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question's title: When the component first renders with `hikeId=A`, and the user triggers `determineData` with a new value for hikeId (`hikeId=B`), `determineData` is still using `postData` values from `hikeId=A`. Setting the `hikeId` property in the call to `setAttributes` does not affect the `hikeId` that is pulled from `props`. `props.attributes` comes from *values, as described by the attributes property **[when the block type was registered](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#attributes)***.

## Update

The sample code below should update Gutenberg block attributes of `Post A` when the user-entered `hikeId` is different from `Post A`'s `attributes.hikeId`. Changes made to `Post B`'s meta data are not automatically reflected in `Post A`'s Gutenberg block attributes. Dynamic updates of this kind might require using [ServerSideRender](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-server-side-render/). *Currently, such updates require updating the hikeId to Post C, saving those changes, then switching the hikeId back to Post B.* Alternatively, the If-condition in the useEffect() callback could be removed. How this is handled depends on whether displayed values should default to block attributes of `Post A` or the current values in `Post B`'s meta data.

[useState](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-element/#usestate), and [useEffect](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-element/#useeffect) are used for local state management.

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';

const { useSelect } = wp.data;

const HikeSummaryData = ( props ) => {
    const {
        attributes,
        setAttributes
    } = props;

    // Initialize local state with value from attributes.
    const [ hikeIdSearchKey, setHikeIdSearchKey ] = useState( attributes.hikeId );
    const [ localAttrs, setLocalAttrs ] = useState( attributes );

    const postData = useSelect( select => {
        return hikeIdSearchKey
            ? select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( 'postType', 'post', hikeIdSearchKey )
            : undefined;
    }, [ hikeIdSearchKey ] );

    useEffect( () => {
        if ( hikeIdSearchKey != attributes.hikeId ) {
            let newAttributes = {
                hikeId: hikeIdSearchKey,
                distance: postData && postData.meta ? postData.meta['alsnuff_hike_summary_distance_meta'] : -1,
                duration: postData && postData.meta ? postData.meta['alsnuff_hike_summary_duration_meta'] : -1,
                ascend: postData && postData.meta ? postData.meta['alsnuff_hike_summary_ascend_meta'] : -1
            };

            // Update the client-side data store for Post A's block
            // attributes with Post B's meta data. The server-side data store
            // (the database) will be updated when the user clicks the Update
            // button.
            setAttributes( newAttributes );

            // Update local state with Post B's meta data for display in the
            // footer of the Post A Edit Post page.
            setLocalAttrs( newAttributes );
        }
    }, [ hikeIdSearchKey ] );

    const determineData = ( newHikeIdSearchKey ) => {
        setHikeIdSearchKey( newHikeIdSearchKey );
    };

    // By default Post A's Gutenberg block attributes are displayed
    // in the footer.
    const { distance, duration, ascend } = localAttrs;

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Hike ID</legend>
                <TextControl
                    value={ hikeIdSearchKey }
                    onChange={ determineData }
                />
            </fieldset>

            <div class="card">
                <footer class="card-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Distanz: { distance != -1 ? (Math.floor(distance / 100) / 10) + 'km' : '-' }</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Dauer: { duration != -1 ? duration + 'h' : '-' }</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Aufstieg: { ascend != -1 ? ascend + 'm' : '-' }</a>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HikeSummaryData;
```

Comment: This is what I observe, yes. But how can I change the code so that I get the correct metadata for the current `hikeId`, not the metadata from the previous `hikeId`?
And what purpose does the extra parameter on `useSelect` play if not triggering it on a chnage?

Comment: @Papa Mufflon The extra parameter on `useSelect` is a *dependency array*. When any of its values change, the `useSelect` callback will execute. Otherwise, a memoized value is returned; in this case, it is assumed you are not interested in any side-effects that may occur (because execution would be skipped). Your code has this set correctly. The problem is that `setAttributes` does not produce the expected outcome of updating `props.attributes.hikeId`. I can update my answer with a solution after knowing if you intended to update Post A with Post B's data.